# What is the meaning of this pattern arg="${arg//\\/\\\\}"

Tags: linux, awk

Please explain the use of pattern

```
arg="${arg//\\/\\\\}"
```

Does it mean exact match?

Comment: You could also have asked me [at the time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743679/100397) and I'd have added an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${var//pattern/replacement}` is a parameter expansion operator of the ksh93 shell.

It expands to the value of `$var` where every occurrence of strings matching the `pattern` have been replaced with `replacement`.

That operator has been copied by a few shells including zsh, bash and mksh. It is otherwise not a standard sh parameter expansion operator.

The pattern is a glob pattern of the shell for instance where `?` matches a single character, `*` matches any sequence of characters, `[abc]` match any one of `a`, `b` or `c` characters (and various shells have additional extensions over those).

If a special glob character is quoted like with `'*'`, `\*`, `"*"`¹, then it is taken literally. `${var//\?/replacement}` for instance replaces question marks instead of every single character.

A backslash must also be quoted like with `\\` or `'\'` or `"\\"` to represent itself so `${var//\\/\\\\}` means expand to the value of `$var` where each occurrence of backslash has been replaced with two backslashes.

---

<sup>¹ Using `\` as opposed to other quoting operators is generally preferable though for the cases where the whole `${...}` is within double quotes. If the patterns and/or replacements are derived from expansions, and those expansions are not quoted (like in `${var//$pattern/$replacement}` as opposed to `${var//"$pattern"/"$replacement"}`, then backslashes must be doubled in ksh93 and bash, but must not in mksh or zsh (at least in their current versions)</sup>