# Awk command not providing output with partial matching in columns 1 and 2

Tags: linux, awk

Please assist with the following script, which is matching variable and providing output. The script is working with *exact* match in columns 1 and 2, but it is not providing an output when there is a *partial* match.

```
cat ~/bin/MYSH

#!/bin/bash
arg="${1:?}"
awk -v arg="${arg//\\/\\\\}" '$1 == arg || $2 == arg' "$@"  inputfile
```

inputfile-

```
1111       1111RETAIL          RETAIL8888Node  
2222       2222RETAIL          RETAIL7777Node 
3333       3333AUDITTEST       AUDIT6666Node
4444       4444AUDIT           AUDIT3333Node
5555       5555SALE            SALE4444Node
6666       6666SALE            SALE2222Node
7777       7777FINANCE         FINANCE1111Node
8888      8888FINANCE          FINANCE5555Node
```

This script is giving output by searching in column 1 or 2 by putting exact matching word like below.

```
$ MYSH 6666
6666       6666SALE            SALE2222Node

$ MYSH 4444AUDIT
  4444       4444AUDIT           AUDIT3333Node
```

I also need this script to provide output when there are 2-3 or any matching characters also in column 2 like below.

Expected output-

```
$ MYSH 4444AU
  4444       4444AUDIT           AUDIT3333Node
```

OR

```
 MYSH 7777FINAN
  7777       7777FINANCE         FINANCE1111Node
```

Comment: You could benefit from reading [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern)

Comment: I know what `arg="${arg//\\/\\\\}"` does but why are you doing it? There's nothing in your question to suggest you need it and if you do need it then there's probabl a better solutiyon to whatever problem you're trying to solve by using it.

Comment: You already have [an answer that does this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743679/100397) in yesterday's question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test `$1 == arg` is *true* if the first field is identical to the variable `arg`'s value.  To test whether the value of `arg` can be found somewhere in `$1`, you may use the `index()` function.  This function returns the position where the substring was found, or zero if it wasn't found:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

arg=${1:?} awk 'index($1,ENVIRON["arg"]) || index($2,ENVIRON["arg"])' inputfile
```

If you want the substring to match only at the start of the fields, then check that the return value from the `index()` function is 1:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

arg=${1:?} awk 'index($1,ENVIRON["arg"])==1 || index($2,ENVIRON["arg"])==1' inputfile
```

I'm also passing the script's first argument as an environment variable into the `awk` command, allowing us to use it without changing backslashes into double ones.

One *could* also use `$1 ~ ENVIRON["arg"]` (or `$1 ~ "^" ENVIRON["arg"]` to only match at the start) which would perform a regular expression match with the user-supplied value as the regular expression against the first field's value.  This is, however, not appropriate unless the user is aware that they are supplying a *regular expression* rather than a string.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda... it looks not working, below error i am getting..                                                    awk: fatal: cannot open file `4444AU' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: @anukalps I have changed it so that the script is using the input from the file called `inputfile`, as in your code. However, I'm confused about why your code uses `"$@"` as that would surely generate the same error.